# Dynamically change label when pressing button - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In this there are buttons and when they are pressed I want the label to be changed to that order of operation for example when the Subtraction button is pressed I want the sign to change to a subtraction sign. Here is a picture of the storyboard. https://www.dropbox.com/s/sh61xss16xr2t0t/Screenshot%202014-10-11%2022.05.48.png?dl=0
Simply when I press a different button I want the operating sign to change dynamically.

```
    @IBAction func addFunctionButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        //Adding Function
    }

    @IBAction func subtractionFunctionButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        //Subtracting Function
    }

    @IBAction func multiplicationFunctionButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        //Multiplication Function
    }

    @IBAction func divisionFunctionButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        //Divivsion Function
    }
```

This is done in the Swift Programming Language

If you have any questions or concerns please comment them down below

Comment: study this tutorial on a tip calculator: http://www.raywenderlich.com/74438/swift-tutorial-a-quick-start

Comment: Where should I be looking, I don't see it talking about changing labels dynamically @SteveRosenberg

Comment: I would do the entire tutorial.  There are also many example apps here:  https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=calculator+swift

Comment: You mean the label of the button? Or another label to be changed by touching the button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to change the label, you need a reference to it. You need to make an `@IBOutlet` and then change the label through that.

I see that you have `@IBActions` already, so maybe you know that process already. Open your storyboard and view controller source side by side in the assistant editor. Then select the label. Switch to the connections inspector and then drag from the small circle next to "New Referencing Outlet" and into the view controller source file. This should create the `@IBOutlet` for you.

Then it is just a matter of changing the label, e.g.

```
@IBOutlet weak var MyLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func subtractionFunctionButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    //Subtracting Function
    MyLabel.text = "-"
}
```

Comment: `MyLabel` is declared to be implicitly unwrapped, so you don't need the '?' when you reference it in the method, but I suppose it's safer to do it the way you've done it.

Comment: Thank you @NRitH - I agree that and have updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can use the following for setting the text dynamically.
myButton.setTitle("My Text", for: .State) where state can you as per your requirements.
In Swift the .titleLabel.text doesn't work when you are trying to set the label dynamically.